# jquery validation position in form

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a text box and done validations using jquery but the validation errors are displaying next to text box. How to align the validation error to get displayed in particular location.

Comment: Without code, a better explanation and/or an image of what you want you can't expect anyone to know. Think about it as if you were reading your question "i want x in the right position!" (what defines right?)

Comment: And yet another bad question rewarded with a single lucky guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you using jquery validate plugin just add this code

```
 $("element").validate({
      errorLabelContainer: $("element"),
      errorClass: ".class"
 });
```